# How to create different List inside one storing file

Tags: c#, oop, serialization, file-handling

I have created one List like this (**List-Lecture**-) and I used to store data inside one file.so i created *(**Lecture.bin)*** file. my Question is -> if I need to insert another List like *(**List-salary**-)* and need to store inside the previous file that's means *(**Lecture.bin**)* is it possible to store? Or do I need to create another storing file like *(**salary.bin)***???    I have given my code below .please give a solution. thank you

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace XYZ_System
{
public class fileAccessLectureCls
{
    private string lectureFilename = "Lecture.bin";


    public List<Lecturer> loadAllLecturer()
    {
        List<Lecturer> lst = null;
        if (File.Exists(lectureFilename))
        {
            Stream stream = File.Open(lectureFilename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bin = new BinaryFormatter();
            lst = (List<Lecturer>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            lst = new List<Lecturer>();
        }
        return lst;
    }     
    public bool SetLectureDetails(Lecturer ObjLecture)
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            List<Lecturer> Leclist = this.loadAllLecturer();

            Leclist.Add(ObjLecture);


            stream = File.Open(lectureFilename, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter bnformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            bnformatter.Serialize(stream, Leclist);
            flag = true;

         }
        catch
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
        return flag;
    }

    public List<Lecturer> GetLectureDetails()
    {
        List<Lecturer> LecList = null;
        Stream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = File.Open(lectureFilename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bnformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            LecList = (List<Lecturer>)bnformatter.Deserialize(stream);
            loadAllLecturer();
        }
        catch
        {
            //throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
        return LecList;

    }
```

Comment: Create a separate binary file for every object, not only it will keeps things separated, your code will not break when deserializing it back

Comment: Create a dedicated type to store all items (lists in your case) as members (properties or fields) which you want to serialize/deserialize. Serialize that type instead of serializing list directly. My opinion: don't use `BinaryFormatter` unless you must ([xml](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part) or [json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) are more flexible formats).

Comment: so the better option is i need to create salary.bin file?

Comment: My blind guess, without knowing of what you try to achieve in general is that you have two options : Either create class that aggregates *all* other data (like `List<Lecturer>` etc) and save it to the same file or create separate files for every new class

Comment: ya.. ok thank you for ur idea.. according to OOP concept which concept is best.. put all list in one file or need to created separate file?.. this for education purpose...